# Bucle ó condición para buscar datos en una columna de Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, bucles, dataframe

El código, a la hora de plasmar los datos de la fila correspondiente en función del (telefono) del contacto, funciona correctamente, pero quisiera previamente añadir una condición ó bucle para en caso de no existir dicho dato, que aparezca un mensaje de error, si no, que continúe su proceso normal. Pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar... ¿Alguien que pueda echarme una mano? Se agradecería!

La primera línea comentada, ¿no es necesario en este caso abrir el archivo por via diferente a DataFrame verdad?
***if df.Telefono == tel***  Es donde no consigo hacer que funcione.

```
def elimina_telefono():
    # fichero = open("Agenda_Telefónica.csv", "r+")
    df = pd.read_csv("Agenda_Telefónica.csv")
    tel = int(input("Introduzca el teléfono a consultar: "))
    **if df.Telefono == tel:**
        print(df[df.Telefono == tel].head())
        si_no = input("¿Desea eliminar éste contacto? (si/no): ")
        if si_no == "si":
            new_df = df.drop(df[df.Telefono == tel].index)
            new_df.to_csv("Agenda_Telefónica.csv", index=False)
            print("¡Contacto eliminado!")
            menu()
        else:
            menu()
    else:
        print("Ningún valor con dicho teléfono")
        menu()
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` sin esa información no es posible saber el formato en el que guardas los teléfonos. ¿Cuál es el problema? No es muy claro lo que quieres lograr, ¿Únicamente quieres mostrar un error si no se encuentra el teléfono?

Comment: Buen día, disculpa la falta de código, soy nuevo en esto y lancé mi pregunta sin mucho detalle. Guardo la información en un archivo(.csv),(En otra función de "agregar_telefono" que funciona correctamente). Siempre que no se encuentra un teléfono aparece las especificaciones del Dataframe y él mismo vacío (indicando que no hay información) pero quisiera sustituirlo  por algo más legible, como con un mensaje de: ("No se ha encontrado ningún valor"). Y para ello deberia crear una condición o for, pero no obtengo el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando haces la comparación en el `if` estás comparando la serie (Es decir, la columna entera) con la variable `tel` por eso no funciona

Lo que podrías hacer es hacer una consulta ([`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)) del teléfono que ingresas con `input()` y revisar si el `dataframe` resultante está vacío o no

Como no agregaste tus datos cree un `dataframe` genérico (En el archivo "sample.csv"), también tuve que comentar varias líneas ya que no agregaste la función de `menu()` (También comenté la línea que crea el nuevo archivo csv para que no lo hiciera en mi computadora y en lugar de eso imprimo el mismo `dataframe` después de hacer `drop`)

```
    Tel         Nombre
0   123-456-798 Juan
1   222-333-444 Pedro
2   345-158-945 El piojo
3   222-333-444 Pedro2
```

**Nota:** El formato de teléfono es genérico y tendrás que adaptarlo a tu código
**Nota:** En los datos hay nombres diferentes con el mismo teléfono para mostrar que elimina varias filas

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import pandas as pd
def elimina_telefono():
    
    df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
    tel = input("Introduzca el teléfono a consultar: ")
    if not df.query(f'Tel == "{tel}"').empty:
        print(df[df['Tel'] == tel].head())
        si_no = input("¿Desea eliminar éste contacto? (si/no): ")
        if si_no == "si":
            df = df.drop(df[df['Tel'] == tel].index)
            #new_df.to_csv("Agenda_Telefónica.csv", index=False)
            print("¡Contacto eliminado!")
            print(df)
            #menu()
        #else:
            #menu()
    else:
        print("Ningún valor con dicho teléfono")
        #menu()

elimina_telefono()
```

Al buscar el teléfono "222-333-444" y eliminarlo obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`

```
           Tel    Nombre
0  123-456-798      Juan
2  345-158-945  El piojo
```

Si se busca un teléfono que no exista obtenemos el siguiente mensaje

```
[In]:  Introduzca el teléfono a consultar:  123-123-123
[Out]: Ningún valor con dicho teléfono
```

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato! 
He probado tu recomendación. Cuando aplico la función (if not df.query(f'Tel == "{tel}"').empty:) directamente me salta al "else" indicando "Ningún valor con dicho teléfono" exista el teléfono o no realmente...
Sólo, si quito el "not" de la condicion (if df.query(f'Tel == "{tel}"').empty:) entonces me aparece el telefono buscado y que realmente sí existe, pero en caso de insertar uno erróneo sigue en las mismas de aparecer un dataframe vacío y no el mensaje deseado. Es curioso, podría subir de nuevo todo mi código para verlo mejor, es muy breve. Gracias igualmente!

Comment: Yo creo que debes revisar el formato de los teléfonos en tus datos, podría ser que tuviera espacios de más y no se vean. Podrías utilizar `if not df.query(f'Tel.str.contains("{tel}")', engine='python')`. También ten en cuenta que yo renombré la columna en lugar de "Telefono" en mi ejemplo es únicamente "Tel", si solo copiaste y pegaste podría ser ahí el error

Answer (score 0):

Al final conseguí solucionar mi problema, la verdad que me llevo tiempo ya que no entendía muy bien la lógica del `(pandas.DataFrame.query)` y sobre todo, que soy junior todavía. Gracias por la ayuda @HeytalePazguato. Aquí dejo mi código completo.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from csv import *
import pandas as pd


def obten_telefono():
    df = pd.read_csv("Agenda_Telefónica.csv")
    tel = input("Introduzca el teléfono a consultar: ")
    if not df.query(f'Telefono == {tel}').empty:
        print(df.query(f'Telefono == {tel}'))
        menu()
    else:
        print("Ningún valor con dicho teléfono")
        menu()


def inserta_telefono():
    fichero = open("Agenda_Telefónica.csv", "a")
    nombre = input("Introduzca nombre: ")
    apellidos = input("Introduzca apellidos: ")
    while True:
        telefono = input("Introduzca un telefono de 9 digitos: ")
        if 10 > len(telefono) > 8:
            datos = nombre + "," + apellidos + "," + telefono + "\n"
            fichero.write(datos)
            fichero.close()
            print("!Añadido a la agenda!")
            menu()
        else:
            print("El teléfono es erróneo")


def elimina_telefono():
    fichero = open("Agenda_Telefónica.csv", "a")
    df = pd.read_csv("Agenda_Telefónica.csv")
    tel = input("Introduzca el teléfono a consultar: ")
    if not df.query(f'Telefono == {tel}').empty:
        print(df.query(f'Telefono == {tel}'))
        si_no = input("¿Desea eliminar éste contacto? (si/no): ")
        if si_no == "si":
            new_df = df.drop(df.query(f'Telefono == {tel}').index)
            new_df.to_csv("Agenda_Telefónica.csv", index=False)
            print("¡Contacto eliminado!")
            menu()
        else:
            menu()
    else:
        print("Ningún valor con dicho teléfono")
        menu()


def menu():
    print("\nOpciones:\n"
          "1.Consultar un teléfono\n"
          "2.Añadir nuevo teléfono\n"
          "3.Eliminar un teléfono\n")
    opcion = input("Escoja una opción: ")
    while True:
        if opcion == "1":
            obten_telefono()
        elif opcion == "2":
            inserta_telefono()
        elif opcion == "3":
            elimina_telefono()
        else:
            print("Escoja una opción entre el 1 y el 3")
            menu()


menu()
```

Las columnas `(Nombre, Apellidos y Telefono)` las he tenido que crear de forma externa desde el archivo CSV. No he sabido hacerlo desde el mismo código. Gracias!